# php process does not die if parent alive

Tags: php, process

I have a rails app which initiates php script using:
`php -f aa.php` 
The php script has at the beginning

`set_time_limit(60); // 1 minute
ini_set('max_execution_time',60);`

But the php script does not die even after two minutes.
I verified using `ps -ef | grep php` and the process is still running.

Does it not die because the parent ( rails app) is alive ?

I have verified the `safe_mode` is off for php

Comment: Are you certain it is the same php process?

Comment: What is the script doing?

Comment: apparently it's executing for > 2 minutes

Comment: also when you run it like that, I believe it runs as a separate process then your ruby.  Is it possible it is blocking, waiting for input, in this state it's "dormant" and wont even know to check it's time limit, I've come across this running php as a worker for RabbitMq, it was blocked and just sat there, then when a job came it died, because it exceeded the max execution time.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix yes I am certain its the same php process because of the params I pass in. Let me try to search more on the dormant state by logging some more info into script

Comment: @michael It has opened a TCP connection with external service and within a loop it keeps querying database.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, [see this Note from php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php), the script won't stop because of set_time_limit as long as there is f.e. a DB query

NOTE:

The set_time_limit() function and the configuration directive max_execution_time only affect the execution time of the script itself. Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution of the script such as system calls using system(), stream operations, database queries, etc. is not included when determining the maximum time that the script has been running. This is not true on Windows where the measured time is real.

---

You might set a timeout function in your loop so that it stops after a minute or whatever time you wish